# Sync exchange with local calendar WITHOUT granting permissions to gmail or Samsung

Tags: sync, calendar, exchange

It's pretty simple, what I want, I think:

- 1 local/offline-only calendar on the phone (default Samsung app)
- 1 on-line exchange calendar (automatically synced)
- ability to show one or the other or both at the same time in the same view
- notifications coming from both calendars, as if they're both local

I do NOT want:

- to associate a google account with the phone
- the gmail app to be in any way involved
- to accept Samsung's request to hold my personal information for 5 years on their servers
- any kind of sync involving e-mail, contacts etc etc.

It amazes me that this seems nearly impossible to do. Is it/how?

Comment: I don't see a problem here Exchange is and was never linked in any way to a Google account. The only "relationship" is that modern Android devices no longer have an mail app for Exchange, instead Google wants you to use the GMail app. But which ap you use is your choice. And as far as I know there is no data exchange with Samsung unless you create/use a Samsung account.

Comment: I'll try to clarify further. I don't want e-mail in the picture at all: in particular, I don't want GMail to play any role in the process. What I'm interested in is the calendar. I have a (default Samsung) calendar app. I want *it* to be the interface to the exchange calendar and to the local calendar on the phone. I would expect the app to provide an option "add remote calendar" where I can enter my exchange credentials and from that moment on, events from the remote (exchange) calendar show up next to events stored locally on my phone.

Comment: Android does not work this way. You have to add the Exchange account to your Android accounts list and then you can select what to sync (mail, calendar, contacts). Now the calendar will be visible in the calendar app (which seems to some Samsung modified version on your device).

Comment: Why is the user required to grant permission to Gmail when adding an Exchange account to the Calendar?

Comment: @Robert if you disable Gmail on an android device (via the app settings panel), you are no longer presented with the option to add an exchange account and if you previously added an exchange account its calendars disappear when you disable Gmail -- so there does appear to be a relationship between Gmail/Google when connecting to Exchange and it does not appear to be managed by an external android service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this using the https://framagenda.org/apps/calendar/ calendar and the DAVx5 app, which uses the caldav protocol. DAVx5 syncs nicely between the built-in calendar app on my phone and the web interface at framagenda.org.

I can define as many calendars as I like ("personal", "business"...) and sync them and can have a local phone calendar (which I no longer use).